# How to fix this issue with categorical variable in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I'm struggling with this issue in R.
I'm trying to run a regression. The first variable is a categorical variable, which I'll call DistanceGroup. Distance group has 4 different values - 0, 1, 2, 3. Each observation fits into one of these four categories.

The purpose of the regression is to see the impact of DistanceGroup on the variable HSGradRate (high school graduation rate), but I want to add a control for the variable "PovertyRate", which is the poverty rate (It's a continuous variable, from 0.1 to 26.9).

What I've tried so far is running the following code

```
HSGradModel  <- lm(HSGradRate ~ DistanceGroup + PovertyRate, data = df)
```

My issue here is that the output comes out like this:

```
Coefficients:
                  Estimate  Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      1.613e-01   1.246e-02   12.948    < 2e-16 ***
DistanceGroup    1.487e-02   6.203e-04   23.972    < 2e-16 ***
PovertyRate0.1  -6.315e-02   3.240e-02   -1.949   0.051306 .  
PovertyRate0.2  -5.521e-02   2.205e-02   -2.504   0.012280 *  
PovertyRate0.3  -4.359e-02   2.025e-02   -2.152   0.031398 *  
PovertyRate0.4  -2.197e-02   2.044e-02   -1.075   0.282461   
.
.
.
PovertyRate26.9 1.372e-01    1.559e-02    8.798   < 2e-16 ***
```

I want PovertyRate to be just 1 variable in the multiple regression, I don't want it to be treated as a categorical variable. Is there any way for me to do this?

Comment: It would help to [see the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) - for example the output from `dput(df)`, or at least the structure of the data, `str(df)`. However, it looks as though the column `PovertyRate` was interpreted as a character variable when the data was read into R, rather than a numeric variable, so that's what you need to understand and fix.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by neilfsw, the variable is not numerical as it is. So either transform it:

`df$PovertyRate <- as.numeric(df$PovertyRate)`

or simply do

`lm(HSGradRate ~ DistanceGroup + as.numeric(PovertyRate), data = df)`

EDIT:
If the variable is a factor, this will not work, as pointed out in the comments. You'll need to transform it to numerical using another method.

Comment: That's incorrect, since PovertyRate appears to be a factor, with your method, [.1, .2, .3, .4] would become [2, 3, 4, 5], see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/6574038).

Comment: Where did you see that the variable was a factor??